# If li has a sub menu prevent default and reveal prevent child links else make links clickable

Tags: jquery

In the below menu I want links to behave as normal if there are no sub-menu links, otherwise the parent link should prevent default and then a class should be set on the on the `submenu`  that will reveal the previously hidden sub-menu items. The problem is that I can't get `$(this).next(".submenu").toggleClass("opened");` to work presumably because it's already contained within a conditional that itself is referencing `$(this)`.

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/508399/) and code below. Thanks in advance.

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="http://test.com">top 1</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li><a href="">sub 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">sub 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="">sub 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="https://google.com">top 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://google.com">top 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```css
.wrap .submenu {
    display: none;
}
.submenu.opened {
    display: block;
}
```

```js
if (
    $(".wrap ul li")
        .has(".submenu")
        .addClass("hasSubMenu")
);


$(".wrap ul li").click(function(e) {
    console.log("a");
    // we only want to target <li> that have a <ul> sub-menu
    if ($(this).hasClass("hasSubMenu")) {
        // first prevent default on the link
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log($(this));
        // now find .submenu and add class
        $(this)
            .next(".submenu")
            .toggleClass("opened");
    } else {
        console.log("test: no submenu");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I may have an answer. Within the initial `$(this)`I stored the internal  `$(this)` inside a var. I've no idea why this should work but it seems to work all the same.

```
if (
    $(".wrap ul li")
        .has(".submenu")
        .addClass("hasSubMenu")
);


$(".wrap ul li").click(function(e) {
    console.log("a");
    // we only want to target <li> that have a <ul> sub-menu
    if ($(this).hasClass("hasSubMenu")) {
        var $this = $(this)
        // first prevent default on the link
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log($(this));
        // now find .submenu and add class
        $this
            .find(".submenu")
            .toggleClass("opened");
    } else {
        console.log("test: no submenu");
    }
});
```